# how install powerlaw python package

Tags: python, pip, installation, spyder, power-law

I need to install the powerlaw package in python.
if I call from the prompt, the python list turns out to be installed.
Instead when I open spyder for python it doesn't recognize the package.
how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your command prompt and try this one;

```
 conda install -c mlgill powerlaw
```

Comment: in anaconda prompt? could you explain how to do it, I'm not practical @yagizcandegirmenci

Comment: Doesn't makes sense if you are not using a virtual enviroment, open a terminal/cmd and paste that it will automaticly downloaded, like pip.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example install it via conda/mamba using the conda-forge channel as follows. The answer from Yagiz Degirmenci does not work because the conda package in the channel `mlgill` is only compatible with Python 3.5 and that's deprecated.

The following works:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge powerlaw
```

Pip should also work:

```sh
pip install powerlaw
```